# how to delete subfolder in ADLS gen2 via azure databricks

Tags: powershell, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to delete ADLS Gen2 subfolder with specific name using databricks dbutils but not able to perform wild card recursion.

```
e.g. 
adlsstorageaccount/container1/folder2/folder3/folderA/**abc**/.parquet
adlsstorageaccount/container1/folder2/folder3/folderB/**abc**/.parquet
adlsstorageaccount/container1/folder2/folder3/folderC/**abc**/.parquet
```

Need to delete subfolder name "abc" & its contents only, entire path is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

We have reproduced the same Folders in our environment and here are the commands that worked.

```
$FileSystemName="<Your Container Name>"
$dirname="folder2/folder3/folderA/abc/"
$ctx=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName '<Your Storage Account>' -StorageAccountKey '<Your Access Key>'
Remove-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname
```

and then confirm it with Y - 'yes'

Here are the screenshots for your reference

**Before using the command execution**
[image]

**After the command execution**
[image]

**REFERENCES:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#delete-a-directory

Comment: Thanks, how to run loop for $dirname ? given I need to traverse all subfolders inside container & delete a folder named "abc"  ?

Comment: AFAIK we need to traverse to the whole path and delete the file or the folder.

Comment: yes, actually the requirement is I need to traverse all folders inside ADLS Gen2 container & delete only a directory with name "abc", looking for a way to achieve this so I can avoid manually updating the path everytime.

Answer (score 1):

you need just use magic command %sh in databricks and remove it with wilcard using standard linux commands, something like:

```
%sh
rm /dbfs/mnt/adlsstorageaccount/container1/folder2/folder3/folderA/*abc*/*.parquet
```

Comment: Thanks, if you notice folderA, B & C are getting changed, means I have to traverse all folders inside container & just delete folder named "abc" ...